# How to set class fields using keys?

Tags: c#, .net

I wrote a generic method which should let us send type, an array which includes field names and an array which includes field values. I need to get class field by key from a dictionary and set value from dictionary to these fields and create new instance of this object

```
private static T test<T>(T obj, string[] fieldArr, string[] valueArr)
    {
        Type type = obj.GetType();

        List<string> data = new List<string>();
        var bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Instance |
                           BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                           BindingFlags.Public;
        List<PropertyInfo> props = type.GetProperties(bindingFlags).ToList();

        Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        FieldInfo[] fieldInfos = type.GetFields();

        for (int i = 0; i < fieldArr.Length; i++)
        {
            dict.Add(fieldArr[i], valueArr[i]);
        }

        var de = new List<PropertyInfo>();

        foreach (var item in dict)
        {
            var fi = type.GetProperty(item.Key);
            object obji = null;
            fi.SetValue(obji, item.Value);
            de.Add(fi);
        }


        return T;
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: If `T` isn't an interface or a base class, you are better off directly working with the POCO at runtime and translating the values to the fields there instead of using reflection inside a generic method.

Comment: If your generic expects a certain type of object to come in (let's say this method will only expect objects that are Dictionaries) you can explicitly define the type of object you want. If you go `private static T test<T>(T obj, string[] fieldArr, string[] valueArr) where T : IDictionary` then the function knows that whatever the generic is it will use the properties and methods in the Dictionary interface.